# Vue 3: Setup Script, TS Problem: "An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module."

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

when using in Vue 3 the setup script with typescript, I get an error in vscode saying:
"An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module."

That happens for external libs and own vue components.

i. e.:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  // ...

  // ASSETS
  import SvgCircle from '@/assets/img/IconsSvg/SvgCircle.vue';

  // MODELS
  import { IApiParams } from '@/models/api/apiparams.interface
  //  import { EBp } from '@/models/enum/baseParams.enum';

  // LIBS
  import justSafeGet from 'just-safe-get';

  // ...
</script>
```

All these are getting red lines in vscode. Others like import from vue or vue-router or own composables do not get red line.
I do not find something helpful to fix it.

Anybody understands that and has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not repeat the error with enums (in SFC) but with interfaces. That's why I added now an interface import to my description.

After a longer search I found a working solution.

### Solution 1: "import type"

`import type { IApiParams } from '@/models/api/apiparams.interface'`

### Solution 2: "Import * as"

```js
import * as IApi from '@/models/api/apiparams.interface';

const apiParmams: IApi.IApiParams = {
    // ...
}
```

Both seem to not throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule you should only import first.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import SvgCircle from '@/assets/img/IconsSvg/SvgCircle.vue'; // ASSETS
  import { EBp } from '@/models/enum/baseParams.enum'; // MODELS
  import justSafeGet from 'just-safe-get'; // LIBS
  ... // Any code here
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't appear as though the error the OP is sharing relates to your solution. I would expect undeclared identifier errors if there was an issue with import ordering.

Comment: The imports are first, (// ... indicates just more imports on top). I just like to leat lines breath. But thanks.

Comment: Actually with Setup SFC I fancy to import things, where it is needed. Like with options api vs compostion api, I like to bungle everything related at one place. Would that cause problems or is it more a convention?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is after your `<script>` tag and before the first `import`:

```
  // ...

  // ASSETS
```

You cannot have any code there: the `import` statements need to be right after the `<script>` tag.

There are multiple [limitations](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations)