# Vue 3 Resolving Image Assets Build

Tags: vuejs3, vite

So I'm trying to build and deploy a Vue 3 website using Heroku. When I test the website locally using `npm run dev` it works just fine. However, when building I get the following error

Error:

```
Could not resolve './assets/Design%20Pics/Drone/7_0030.png' from src/App.vue
error during build:
Error: Could not resolve './assets/Design%20Pics/Drone/7_0030.png' from src/App.vue
    at error (C:\Users\stove\Desktop\Aero Website\AeroWebsite\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:198:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (C:\Users\stove\Desktop\Aero Website\AeroWebsite\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:22508:24)
    at C:\Users\stove\Desktop\Aero Website\AeroWebsite\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:22471:26
```

code:

*Note: it's a fragment of the overall code, this is where the "issue" is. Also, I'm using Bulma to style*

```
<section class="section">

<!-- to center columns, the parent has to be the image which is impossible -->
    <div class="card">

      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-2by1 level">
          <img src="./assets/Design Pics/Drone/7_0030.png" alt="Drone Image" width="1280" height="720">

          <div id="title-overlay-pad" class="is-overlay level-right">
            <div id="title-overlay-background" class="has-text-centered">
              <p id="title-home-page">delivAERO</p>
              <p id="tagline-home-page">Revolutionizing the World's Delivery Infrastructure</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </div>

    </div>


  </section>
```

Heiarchy:

[image]

---

**UPDATE: ANOTHER SOLUTION**

After getting a lot of help from *Daniel*, using the import method mentioned in their answer I was still getting errors. I assume this is more about the way the project is setup, but I found another solution.
The way, this [post mentions is](https://rightclick.com.au/2022/04/13/loading-images-in-vue-3/#:%7E:text=import%20imgName%20from%20%22%40/assets/img/img_asset.webp%22%20%3B), it should be imported is as

`import img from '@/assets/path/to/img.png'`

*Note: I have all my images in the assets folder on the src directory*

However, this may give the following error:

```
error TS1232: An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a namespace or module.
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70851447/vue-3-setup-script-ts-problem-an-import-declaration-can-only-be-used-in-a-na), the reason for this error is because imports should be declared first before any Javascript code.

In other words, it should look like:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  //any other imports here, before javascript code
  import img from '@/assets/path/to/img.png'; // ASSETS
  
  // Javascript code here
</script>
```

I'll still be accepting *Daniel*'s answer as I believe that should be the solution for most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update

both require and import should work with default setup (used latest ATTOW vue-cli 5.0.6 and vue 3.2.13)

I've setup a new project with vue-cli and updated the helloWorld component with:

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <img src="/images/logo.png">
    <img :src="img"/>
    <img :src="require('../assets/logo.png')">
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import img from "../assets/logo.png"
</script>
```

All three versions work for me. If you are still having issues, I'd recommend the 1st option `<img src="/images/logo.png">`. The only thing you need to do is to move the image (`logo.png`) into the public folder (`public/images/logo.png`)

I've also noticed that with the default settings, the images that are "imported" or "required" get injected into the js as base64, which I'm not a fan of, so unless the configuration is updated to handle those, I'd recommend the first option.

AS an aside, I would also recommend removing spaces from the resource and directory names. You have a space in `Design Pics`, which servers *should* all handle properly, but it's not guaranteed .

---

When you use the image like this in the template, it is handled as a string

```html
<img :src="./assets/Design Pics/Drone/7_0030.png" alt="Drone Image" width="1280" height="720">
```

In order for Vue to bundle the asset it needs to know about it.

you can do this reference in-template

You can import it and then pass the reference the image as the variable in the template

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="myImg" alt="Drone Image" width="1280" height="720">
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import myImg from './assets/Design Pics/Drone/7_0030.png'; // import asset

</script>
```

or use `require` in the template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="require(./assets/Design Pics/Drone/7_0030.png)" alt="Drone Image" width="1280" height="720">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Also, since I'm using Vue 3 `export default` does not work and will cause errors if I use it. I believe the Vue 3 equivalent is just using the import variable name (in this case `myImg`).

Comment: if you are using `<script setup>` with the _Composition API_, you can skip passing the variable to template via `data` definition. The rest should be the same

Comment: I realize I had a mistake in there, fixed that and added another solution

Comment: using the import method I get the error `error TS1232: An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a namespace or module.`
when using the require method I get `error TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add 'node' to the types field in your tsconfig.`
Also, I think you for got to put qutations around the path, so it would be `:src="require('./assets/Design Pics/Drone/7_0030.png')"` otherwise you get syntax errors

Comment: hard to tell, it might be setup dependent. I'll update answer with additional options